# Insertion sort with external array?

Tags: java, insertion-sort

I'm using java. I have an array of floating point numbers, and I also have an array of integer arrays.

floats[i] corresponds to intarrays[i].

I've set up a insertion sort to sort the floats, and it does so correctly. However, I'm struggling to figure out how to sort the intarrays in the exact same fashion that the floats were.

Here is my code for sorting the floats.

```
for(int i = 1; i < floats.length; i++){
   float key = floats[i];
   int j;
   for(j = i - 1; (j >= 0) && (key < floats[j]); j--){
      floats[j + 1] = floats[j];
   }
   floats[j + 1] = key;
}
```

Essentially, how should I integrate the second array into this so it sorts in the exact same way?

NOTE: I can't use ArrayLists.

Comment: Is your goal to sort `intarrays` based on its own contained values or to order `intarrays` such that `float[i]` corresponds to `intarrays[i]` as you said before the sort?

Comment: Essentially every value in floats corresponds to the same index for intarrays. The floats gets sorted and rearranged, and it is no longer the case that floats[i] corresponds to intarrays[i]. I need this to be the case, so I need the intarrays to be sorted exactly how the floats were. So the second one you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Use your index trackers (`i` and `j`) to manipulate the positions of `intarrays` alongside `floats`.

Given `float[] floats` and `int[][] intarrays`.

```
for(int i = 1; i < floats.length; i++){
    float key = floats[i];
    int[] intKey = intarrays[i]; // New code, identical to above line
    int j;
    for(j = i - 1; (j >= 0) && (key < floats[j]); j--){
       floats[j + 1] = floats[j];
       intarrays[j + 1] = intarrays[j]; // New code, identical to above line
    }
    floats[j + 1] = key;
    intarrays[j + 1] = intKey; // New code, identical to above line
}
```